# Install old version of ocaml

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I know this is a common question, and I've read many similar threads, but still I can't get it to work.

Due to dependency hell, I need to compile `unison` on `ocaml` version `3.12` on my ubuntu linux (Yakkety Yak) system. Yakkety is packaged with `ocaml 4.x`:

```
$ sudo apt policy ocaml
ocaml:
  Installed: 4.02.3-6ubuntu2
  Candidate: 4.02.3-6ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 4.02.3-6ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

So my first challenge is installing the previous version from a source. Now, according to [ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ocaml&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), Precise (12.04) is packaged with `ocaml 3.12`, and I've added the following lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
```

and running `sudo apt update`

However, the output of `sudo apt policy ocaml` has not changed, and running `sudo apt install ocaml=3.12\*` returns

`E: Version '3.12*' for 'ocaml' was not found`

Any ideas as to why this version is not found after the steps I've taken above?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems, that the `ocaml` package was in some other source than the two lines I'd added.

Eventually, I took the original `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and appended to it that same file but with `yakkety` substituted by `precise`. After that, and `sudo apt update`, I was able to install `ocaml=3.12\*`.

I still needed to install other packages before (`ocaml-nox=3.12\*`, which in turn required `ocaml-base-nox=3.12\*`, etc, etc), but eventually I got it installed.

I still assume there must be an easier way though...